# How to fill a HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> from a text file ?

Tags: java, list, file, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I have a txt file with the form:

```
Key,Value,Value,Value
Key,Value,Value,Value,Value,Value,Value
Key,Value,Value,Value,Value,Value
```

I want to put all the keys with their values in a hashMap. However I dont know how to separate the keys from the values nor fill the nodes of the linkedlists with the values. I've tried to use .split(",") but I think i'm not using it properly.

Comment: Consider showing how you have tried it. It is not a big deal (copy-pasting indented Java code probably becomes a code-block without any further formatting) and people respect a question more when they see the effort. Plus, probably it is easy to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read your file by lines. By every line read, split it to separate Strings and convert Array to LinkedList. Then remove the first element and assign it to variable, cause it's a key, not one of the values. Then add the variable with key and LinkedList with values to HashMap.

Remember to change your filename to whatever your one is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap< String, LinkedList<String> > hm = new HashMap< String, LinkedList<String> >();
    String line, key;
    LinkedList<String> lineSplit;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( new File("data.txt") ) );

        while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ){
            lineSplit = new LinkedList<String>( Arrays.asList(line.split(",")) );
            key = lineSplit.removeFirst();             
            hm.put(key, lineSplit);
        }
        br.close();

    } catch( IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One loop to walk through the lines. For each line, split the string by commas, and create a new linked list with all the values, then add the list to the master hash map under the key (from the same line).